# How to Disable Restore Application to previous State

Tags: wix, windows-installer, clickonce

I have a clickonce application. While uninstalling in some machine "Restore Application to previous State" is enabled and in some machines its disabled.
 I need to disable "Restore Application to previous State" in all machines what should I change in the code to do that.
My Installer code is written in Wix. I am new to Wix ff you guys can point to some good training materials will also be helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify, you are using WiX *and* ClickOnce? I've never heard of anyone doing that. Typically you either use WiX *or* ClickOnce.

From a ClickOnce standpoint, if you make the minimum required version the same as the current version the "Restore" option will go away.